# What causes a query string when requesting jQuery? e.g. /jquery-1.3.2.min.js?_=12553

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I'm troubleshooting a jQuery problem which happens when the HTTP requests for a page load include this query string:

> GET /Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js?_=1255309685187

Normally, the request has no query string and the response status code is 304:

```
GET /Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js
```

However, every so often a query string is appended.  Where does this query string come from?  What does it mean?

The webserver is Visual Studio's Development Server, and I usually see this in IE8.  Occasionally I'll see it in Firefox though.  The app is ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: for the record, if this is a "force a fresh read" to get around caching issues, this is a bad thing.  Having the browser cache something as non-changing as your jQuery library, would be highly beneficial; loading pages faster and causing less strain on your server resources.

I would work hard to make sure this timestamp isn't part of the call.

Answer (score 2):

Generally such a value is a TIMESTAMP representation appended as a query string to ensure that the file you are requesting, in this case jquery-1.3.2.min.js, is not cached.  The unique query string is strictly used for purposes of grabbing the newest version of the file, not one found in your browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

looks like the number after is a unix time. i don't know why this would be automatically appended tho.

possibly some way of getting around browser cache? forcing a reload of the js basically?